# What is causing this CircularDependencyError and how is it fixed?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

When I try to migrate my database I get a `CircularDependencyError`.  I found some information about this in the [Core Exceptions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#post-update) docs and tried to add `post_update=True`, but it didn't solve the issue.  I can see it's a problem of mutual relations between Branch and Card.  How can I solve this error?

These are my models:

```
class Branch(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    Summary = db. Column(db.String(255))
    viewCount = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    onEditFlag = db.Column(db.Integer)
    editorChoice = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    createDateTime = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())

    coverImage = db.Column(db.String(255))

    userId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('branches', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic'))

    rootCardId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('card.id'))
    card = db.relationship('Card',
                           backref=db.backref('childBranches'), post_update=True)

    parentBranchId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('branch.id'))
    parentBranch = db.relation('Branch', remote_side=[id])
    childeBranch = db.relationship("Branch", lazy="joined", join_depth=2)

    parentStreamId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stream.id'))
    stream = db.relationship('Stream',
                             backref=db.backref('childBranches', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic'))

    BranchTagRelation = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=BranchTagRelation,
                                        backref=db.backref('branches', lazy='dynamic'))

    BranchBookMark = db.relationship('User', secondary=BranchBookMark,
                                        backref=db.backref('branchBookmarks', lazy='dynamic'))

    BranchThumbsUp = db.relationship('User', secondary=BranchThumbsUp,
                                        backref=db.backref('branchThumbsUps', lazy='dynamic'))


class Card(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    branchId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('branch.id'))
    branch = db.relationship('Branch', backref=db.backref('cards', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic'))

    streamId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stream.id'))
    stream = db.relationship('Stream', backref=db.backref('cards', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic'))

    order = db.Column(db.Float)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    createDateTime = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    finalEditDateTime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

This is the exception I get when using those models:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manager.py", line 6, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_script\commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 80, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate = True, sql = sql)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 97, in revision
    script.run_env()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\script.py", line 203, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\util.py", line 212, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\compat.py", line 58, in load_module_py
    mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
  File "migrations\env.py", line 72, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations\env.py", line 65, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 7, in run_migrations
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\environment.py", line 688, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\migration.py", line 242, in run_migrations
    self):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 83, in retrieve_migrations
    autogen._produce_migration_diffs(context, template_args, imports)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\autogenerate\api.py", line 137, in _produce_migration_diffs
    autogen_context, object_filters, include_schemas)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\alembic\autogenerate\api.py", line 209, in _produce_net_changes
    for table in metadata.sorted_tables])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3194, in sorted_tables
    return ddl.sort_tables(self.tables.values())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 868, in sort_tables
    return list(topological.sort(tuples, tables))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\topological.py", line 47, in sort
    for set_ in sort_as_subsets(tuples, allitems):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\topological.py", line 34, in sort_as_subsets
    _gen_edges(edges)
CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected. Cycles: set([Table('card', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=<card>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('branchId', Integer(), ForeignKey
('branch.id'), table=<card>), Column('streamId', Integer(), ForeignKey('stream.id'), table=<card>), Column('order', Float(), table=<card>), Column('content', Text(), table=<card>), Column('createDateTime', DateTime()
, table=<card>, default=ColumnDefault(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now at 0x3054650; now>)), Column('finalEditDateTime', DateTime(), table=<card>), schema=None), Table('branch', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer
(), table=<branch>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('title', String(length=255), table=<branch>), Column('Summary', String(length=255), table=<branch>), Column('viewCount', Integer(), table=<branch>, defaul
t=ColumnDefault(0)), Column('onEditFlag', Integer(), table=<branch>), Column('editorChoice', Boolean(), table=<branch>, default=ColumnDefault(False)), Column('createDateTime', DateTime(), table=<branch>, default=Colu
mnDefault(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now at 0x3041930; now>)), Column('coverImage', String(length=255), table=<branch>), Column('userId', Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<branch>), Column('rootCardId', Integer
(), ForeignKey('card.id'), table=<branch>), Column('parentBranchId', Integer(), ForeignKey('branch.id'), table=<branch>), Column('parentStreamId', Integer(), ForeignKey('stream.id'), table=<branch>), schema=None)]) a
ll edges: set([(Table('card', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=<card>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('branchId', Integer(), ForeignKey('branch.id'), table=<card>), Column('streamId', Int
eger(), ForeignKey('stream.id'), table=<card>), Column('order', Float(), table=<card>), Column('content', Text(), table=<card>), Column('createDateTime', DateTime(), table=<card>, default=ColumnDefault(<sqlalchemy.sq
l.functions.now at 0x3054650; now>)), Column('finalEditDateTime', DateTime(), table=<card>), schema=None), Table('StreamBookMark', MetaData(bind=None), Column('streamId', Integer(), ForeignKey('stream.id'), table=<St
reamBookMark>), Column('userId', Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<StreamBookMark>), Column('cardId', Integer(), ForeignKey('card.id'), table=<StreamBookMark>), Column('createDateTime', DateTime(), table=<Stre
amBookMark>, default=ColumnDefault(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now at 0x2ff1c70; now>)), schema=None)),
```

Comment: show your stacktrace.. Just mentioning the error might not be very useful

Comment: thank you for your comment and advice. the log is very long but i'll show you here.

Comment: You have `rootCardId` on `Branch` and `branchId` on `Card`. Typically when defining a one-to-one or one-to-many relation you only place the foreign key on one of the tables. The way you've defined them, loading a `Branch` loads all of its `Card`s which then load all of their `Branch`es, etc. Defining the `backref` on only one of the models should correct the circular dependency.